# Visual Studio: Start ASP.NET application and open webbrowser with currently selected folder as URL

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I had no idea how to word this and thus no idea how to search for it, so hopefully this is not a duplicate.

I have an ASP.NET MVC5 application and let‘s say a `Transaction.cshtml` file that is in the folder `Transaction` (so I have `Transaction/Transaction.cshtml`. Then I have a controller for `GET: Transaction`. Now the default behaviour from VS is to open `host/Transaction/Transaction.cshtml` when I press F5 while `Transaction.cshtml` has the focus. Then I get an error that the viewbag couldn‘t be initialized for example, I have to hit F5 again to continue the execution, switch focus to my webbrowser and change the URL to `host/Transaction` and wait again until everything is initalized. The whole process is annoying.

What I want to have is when I press F5, Visual Studio should open the folder my currently focused file is in. So when I‘m in `Transaction/Transaction.cshtml` it should open `host/Transaction` in my webbrowser.

I have a workaround that takes away some of the annoyance. I just changed in the <kbd>Project Properties</kbd> → <kbd>Web</kbd> the option from `Current Page` to `Start URL` to just open `host/`. But then I have to navigate to `host/Transaction/` manually.

So my question is: **Can I have Visual Studio open the folder where the currently focused file is in when pressing F5?**